# Prevent a parent route's component from firing when landing on child route

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a parent route setup with a single child route. When landing/refreshing the child page the parent component fires, making requests, life cycle hooks etc.

How can I make the child component load without its parent page firing?
Perhaps there is a global routing option or something.

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'child',
        loadChildren: () => import('./child/child.routes'),
      },
    ]
  }
```

Additional:
Above is my `parent.route.ts` and the app is 100% standalone components

Comment: your child component doesn't have independent route from parent. Seems like you load child component via <router-outlet>
If so, when you refresh page, both parent and child will refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parent routes always activate their components when a child route is loaded.

The answer is that when working with dynamic params to drive data you must react to their changes and fetch/display data this way.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  // watch for profile ID change
  this.router.events
    .pipe(filter((event: Event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
    .subscribe((res: NavigationEnd) => {
        this.checkProfileOwner(); 
    });
```

In the case above - watch for new URL props to fetch that profile
Also check if we're on a child page and don't fetch anything

```
if (this.activatedRoute?.firstChild?.routeConfig?.path !== 'id') {
  // do nothing
```

The same rules apply on the child page:

1. confirm if current route is parent or child
2. load/unload/don't load data based on URL

Answer (score 2):

One way to prevent the parent component from being triggered is to use the `skipLocationChange` option when navigating to the child route.

another is to move the code that you do not want to be triggered in the parent component to a shared service and inject that service into the child component. This will ensure that the code is only executed when the child component is loaded.

one more potential solution is to use the `canActivate` guard on the parent route to prevent it from being loaded when the child route is in use.

```
{
  path: '',
  component: ParentComponent,
  canActivate: [ChildGuard],
  children: [
    {
      path: 'child',
      loadChildren: () => import('./child/child.routes'),
    },
  ]
}
```

In this scenario, the ChildGuard would return false, preventing the parent component from being activated.

Another awesome feature that I learned and is best for standalone components. It is to load child route as sibling instead of loading it as child of parent component, this will prevent parent component rendering/firing its lifecycle hooks when navigating to child route.

Parent route:

```
{
  path: 'parent',
  component: ParentComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      component: ChildOutletComponent,
      outlet: 'childOutlet', // define outlet
      loadChildren: () => import('./child/child.routes')
    }
  ]
}
```

template:

```
<router-outlet name="childOutlet"></router-outlet>
```

This option is more flexible and It may improve performance in some cases

Comment: Would it be easier and advised to move the child to its own top-level route? Also, there's no way to simply prevent this from happening? Its strange I havent come across this before.

Comment: @BenRacicot if the parent and child components are mostly independent, then it might be easier to move the child to its own top-level route. but if components tightly related then it makes more sense to keep as child routes and It really depends on your specific use case as well

Comment: btw there is one more option other than mentioned above it is to use child outlet to load it as a sibling, this way parent component will not render, and neither fire its lifecycle hooks, you can find more on the blog

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't

Inside your parent component html you have a `router-outlet`. This is where you children are loaded. YOu say you don't want to load your parent. But if you don't load your parent, there is no place for your children to be loaded.

Comment: Thank you Robin, I think this answer actually solves my specific problem directly. While my UX flows as a `parent page > child page` the logic by no means would require a router. Meaning my child component is not a child even if the UX appears this way in my app.

Answer (score 2):

Your child component doesn't have independent route from parent. Seems like you load child component via

If so, when you refresh page, both parent and child will refresh.

Just rewrite like this, and del `<router-outlet>` in parents template

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'parent',
    component: ParentComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'parent/child',
    component: ChildComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./child/child.routes'),
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hiho I´m not sure what this code is doing and how the route is exported.

```
export const childRoute = import { routeName } from '/child/child.routes'
export { childroute1, childRoute2 } = import { childRoute1, childRoute2 } from '/child/child.routes'
export default routeName = import routeName from '/child/child.routes'

     {
    path: '',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'child',
        loadChildren: () => childRoute2,
      },
    ]
  }
```

The imports should be at the top of the file, after importing with a name for example `{ childRoute2 }` or `{ route as childRoute2 }` u can use it like a variable.

Maybe that will help u. I hope so.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).